# a user installed network manager, and it messed up netplan

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan, ip

So a user install network manger with "sudo snap install networkmanager"

this killed the netplan config, so he used the console to remove networkmanager again. With sudo snap remove networkmanager.

now my problem is. netplan is not working, and there is no network on the machine. If i run netplan try, i get a long list of erros. How do i get network working again on this machine?

ifup is not installed either, its a ubuntu 20 installation. Is there any hope?

[netplan try command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ksGM.png)

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by downloading a live cd, booted that mounted the ubuntu install with lvm, used chroot to enter the old install, and from there reinstall netplan.

booted the system, applyed the old config.